# How to set the section title as a right header using fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, amsart

Within `\documentclass{amsart}` how can I define the `\rightmark` to be the section title, without the number?

I am using the `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: How about providing a starter document such that users willing to help you do not have to do all and can concentrate on the main feature

Comment: In the event that you have multiple `\section`s on the same page, should it be the *first* or the *last* section title on the page?

Comment: i'm not in a position to test anything, but I doubt very much that trying to change this using `fancyhdr` will be successful.  a more likely approach would be to patch the `amsart` `\section` mechanism.  (this is the default for `amsbook`, so some ideas may be found there.)

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because insufficient information has been provided to guess at an answer, and the op has not responded.